# Using sender name and removing HTML entity encoding in Swiftmailer

Tags: 8

I have swiftmailer installed on a Drupal 8 installation. I am using a `hook_mail()` function to edit the message params as follows:

```
function mymodule_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
    $options = array(
        'langcode' => $message['langcode'],
    );
    switch ($key) {
        case 'support_form':
            $message['files'] = $params['files'];
        case 'submit_to_admin':
        case 'submit_to_user':
            $message['from'] = array(\Drupal::config('system.site')->get('mail') => 'site admin name');
            $message['subject'] = t('@title', array('@title' => $params['title']), $options);
            $message['body'][] = Html::escape($params['message']);
            break;
    }
}
```

I am sending the e-mail like this:

```
$mailManager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.mail');
$module = 'mymodule';
$key = 'support_form';
$params['message'] = $message; //defined elsewhere
$params['files'] = $attachments; //defined elsewhere
$params['title'] = $title; //defined elsewhere
$langcode = \Drupal::currentUser()->getPreferredLangcode();
$send = true;
$result = $mailManager->mail($module, $key, $to, $langcode, $params, NULL, $send);
```

The e-mail is sending fine, including attachments (so I know Swiftmailer must be working), but when I receive the e-mail the sender is listed as just the e-mail address and not as "site admin name".

Additionally, any `&` symbol in the body is showing up as `&amp;amp;`

My swiftmailer install is configured according to [this guide](https://arrea-systems.com/Install_use_SwiftMailer_Drupal_8_(part_2_implementation)).

Is there a setting or code piece I am missing that is making this happen?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and did the following to solve the issue with the entities.

```
$text = $message['body'];
$message['body'] = array_map(function ($text) {
  return Markup::create($text);
}, $text);
```

This will convert the body and will not display any entites anymore.